# Connecting Tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Table City Model**

```
class TableCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :near_cities, :foreign_key => "nearcity_id"  
end
```

**NearCity Model**

```
class NearCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table_city
end
```

**Controller**

```
@table_cities = TableCity.find(:all, :conditions=>{:state => params[:gm], :language => params[:sp]}, :include => :near_cities)
```

**View**

```
<% @table_cities.each do |table_city| %>
  <%= table_city.name %>
  <% table_city.near_cities.each do |city| %>        
    <%= city.text %>
  <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

This is not working, Kindly give me some suggestions.

Comment: What is not working? Any error messages you would like to share with us?

Comment: Please, give more precisions. What is not working? What kind of error you you get? What is your setup (version of rails)?

Comment: Which part of this isn't working? Are you getting any error messages? What does your schema for these models look like? Try removing the conditions in your controller to reduce the scope of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationships look strange. A `NearCity` belongs to a `TableCity` therefore, you should be storing the foreign key of the `TableCity` in your `near_cities` table. To achieve this make sure your `near_cities` table has a column called `table_city_id`.

Your models can simply be:

```
class TableCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :near_cities  
end

class NearCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table_city
end
```

Comment: Thank you for kind help. If I need to set foreign_key as a colulmn which dont have suffix "id". I need to mention that, In that case what i can do.

Comment: In that case you have to use `:foreign_key => `. For example: `belongs_to :table_city, :foreign_key => 'nearcity'`.

Comment: @captaintokyo: :foreign_key => 'other_id'... Not works, No error... Its nor connecting the data of belongs table_city.

Comment: class TaxonomicLink < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :taxon_name                                 class TaxonName < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taxonomic_links, :foreign_key => 'name_id' @taxon_names = TaxonName.find(:all, :conditions=>{:genus_name => params[:gm], :corrig => params[:ck1], :type_species => params[:ck2], :sp_epithet => params[:sp]})                          <% @taxon_names.each do |taxon_name| %><%= taxon_name.genus_name %> <% taxon_name.taxonomic_links.each do |tax_link| %>
<%= tax_link.text %><% end %><% end %>

Comment: You are putting `:foreign_key` in the wrong place! Do it like this: `class TaxonomicLink < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :taxon_name, :foreign_key => 'name_id'` and make sure your `taxonomic_links` table has a column called `name_id`.

Comment: If I use :foreign_key as attribute in belongs_to, It shows "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid". It shows none error if i use it as attribute for has_many. I am using Rails 3.0.0

Comment: Once I provided primary_key of taxon_names, it connects and working fine. But as hard part, I dont know the hidden reason behind the "primary key". No other forums and tutorials, i didnt read abt role of primary key in connecting tables...

Comment: I am curious which code exactly you are using now. Could you post it?? `primary_key` is used if the primary key column in your table is something other than `id`.

Comment: I found the reason. The foreign key was not declared before during migration. Because, I do manual migration. The foreign key of taxonomic_links == primary key of taxon_names. Thats, It requires primary key of taxon_name to connect with foreign_key of taxonomic-Links.

Answer (score 0):

In your Models

```
class TableCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :near_cities  
end

class NearCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table_city
end
```

In your migrations

```
class CreateTableCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :table_cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :table_cities
  end
end
```

---

```
class CreateNearCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :near_cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :table_city
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :near_cities
  end
end
```

And then finally in your controller you can do this

```
@table_city = TableCity.find(params[:id]) #one TableCity
@near_cities = @table_city.near_cities    # all near_cities associated with the TableCity
```